# My computer automatically opens Bing when it boots

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, browser, bing

Whenever I boot my Windows 8 computer, my default browser (Chrome, though this happened while IE was my default browser) opens up and automatically opens the [Bing](http://bing.com) homepage. What's causing this and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What have you tried so far? The basics? http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/01/disable-startup-programs-in-windows-8-using-task-manager/

Comment: @AthomSfere I've looked at the scheduled tasks, tried changing default browsers. I don't think Chrome is causing the problem because IE did this for a while too

Answer (score 2):

I guess your browser starts whenever your system starts, so disabling the browser on startup may fix your problem.

1. Go to `run` or press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type `msconfig` navigate to *Startup*
3. Choose Chrome and uncheck the checkmark (checkmark indicates programs which start during boot process)
4. Choose *Apply* and *OK*
5. Reboot your machine

Next time your browser won't start on every boot.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out this question is a duplicate (sorry about that).

The solution is the change the following registry entry to `0`:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet\EnableActiveProbing
```

More detail on this fix is given [here](https://superuser.com/a/623618/202670)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8 open your Task Manager (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and then hit <kbd>T</kbd>) and click on the tab Startup, from here you can disable the applications/programs you do not want to start when Windows 8 is booting. If for some reason it does not solve the problem, download and run Autoruns. Download it from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)