# Why does a website opens each time I log into Windows

Tags: windows, boot

Each time I log into Windows, my default browser Firefox opens this specific website:

http://www.future.net.bd/login?dst=http%3A%2F%2Fgo.microsoft.com%2Ffwlink%2F%3FLinkID%3D219472%26clcid%3D0x409

This happens to all user account in my computer. I searched the startup locations using sysinternal's Autoruns but couldn't find Firefox there.

I recently took a new broadband internet connection. This is happening since then. I haven't installed any software for my ISP. My OS is Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: This wouldn't be explicitly starting Firefox. An attempt at launching any link, from a URL shortcut to a batch file containing `start http://example.com` to any number of other methods will end up launching the default browser. Look for those.

Comment: I noticed that the domain future.net.bd does not exist. Something to log in appears? Where this link from go.microsoft.com leads to? Does this happens only with your computer or to all computers on the network?

Comment: @Bob: Well, the ISP guys simply set up a connection using PPPoE and I don't think they've created anything to run at startup. Everything they did in front of my eyes. Future.Net is the name of the ISP. I'm still puzzled what triggers this launch of website!

Comment: @athosbr99: Nothing appears in log in except that I created a shortcut using rasdial.exe to launch at startup which will connect to Future.Net (my ISP). I guess the go.microsoft.com... is the homepage currently set in IE. I don't know if it happens to other PCs in the network. I don't have that visibility.

Comment: This is the same problem as described here:
http://superuser.com/questions/623617/why-does-windows-8-open-bing-com-by-itself. In my case, because I need to connect to my ISP first, my ISP is showing the log in page.