# Change http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=219472&clcid=0x409 to my captive portal login page

Tags: windows, captive-portal

My ISP uses captive portal which automatically logs out after few minutes of inactivity. Whenever I resume from sleep http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=219472&clcid=0x409 link opens in my default browser. I know of  Windows Network Location Awareness Service will be checking for internet access. I know of registry change can be made to disable this functionality completely (answered here on superuser) [Why does Windows 8 open Bing.com by itself?](https://superuser.com/questions/623617/why-does-windows-8-open-bing-com-by-itself) .

Can I change this default link to point it to my captive portal login page itself directly?? I can't find reference to this anywhere. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it via setting following registry entry from 1 to 0:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet\EnableActiveProbing.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but can you please cite your source for that proposed solution?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please can you write the reference to help OP find more information?

Comment: Here's the research: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_8/windows-8-goes-to-bing-by-itself-all-the-time/386e9a25-8149-4ee6-84b4-65332022c2a7

Comment: I already mentioned this above.